# redirect form based on option selection

Tags: javascript, html

How do I redirect the user based on two options on drop down menu's?

i have read a few similar questions but couldnt relate the advice as the form code I am using is very long and complicated. I have taken out a lot of the code so I hope i'm not missing anything out thats important.

I am trying to redirect the user based on if they pick 
1)Audition Only 
2)Workshop Only or 
3)Workshop + Audition

As well as if they choose to attend

1) London
2) Birmingham
3) Manchester

So that someone doing an Audition in London would get directed to a different place than someone doing an Audition in Manchester.

If you can I would appreciate the help!

```
<form name="signupForm" id="signupForm" target="_top" method="post" action="http://app.greenrope.com/j1.pl?9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b4187c3ac601cb070094b" onsubmit="get_action(this);">

<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td> 
<ul id="teamFields"> 

  <li class="formRow emailRow" id="field_Email"><label class="fieldName" for="signup_Email">Email<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="64" value="" id="signup_Email" class="inputTextField" />
<div id="emailEntryAlert">
</div>
</li> 


<li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User5" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelUser5" for="signup_User5">Please select the closest city to where you live from the list<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label> <select name="User5" id="signup_User5"><option value="">Choose</option> <option value="London" >London</option><option value="Birmingham" >Birmingham</option><option value="Manchester" >Manchester</option></select>
</li> 

</li> 
<li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User8" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelUser8" for="signup_User8">Would you like to attend the workshop and/or audition?<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label> <select name="User8" id="signup_User8"><option value="">Choose</option> <option value="Workshop Only" >Workshop Only</option><option value="Workshop + Audition" >Workshop + Audition</option><option value="Audition Only" >Audition Only</option></select>
</li> 


</ul>
<ul id="teamSelection"> 
<li class="formRow joinRow"><span id="confirmText"> </span>
</li> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="4" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="3" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="1" /> 
</ul> 
</td> 
</tr> </tbody>
</table> 
<div id="reqInfo">* required information
</div> 
<input id="formSubmit" type="submit" name="formSubmit" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: #000000; border-style: solid; border-width: 8px !important; border-color: #d3d3d3 !important; border-radius: 0px !important; padding: 16px !important; background: #a9a9a9 !important; box-shadow: none !important;" value="Sign Me Up" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="Referrer" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="qstring" value="9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b4187c3ac601cb070094b" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="formSubmitCheck" value="1" /> 


<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_action(form) {
        var optn = document.getElementById("signup_User5");
        var optn_value= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var optn = document.getElementById("signup_User8");
        var optn_value= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        if ((optn_value=="Workshop Only") && (optn_value=="London")) {
           window.location.href = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuklondonworkshop";
     } else if ((optn_value=="Workshop Only") && (optn_value=="Birmingham")) {
           window.location.href = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcukbirminghamworkshop";
     } else if ((optn_value=="Workshop Only") && (optn_value=="Manchester")) {
           window.location.href = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcukmanchesterworkshop";
    } else if ((optn_value=="Audition Only") && (optn_value=="London")) {
           window.location.href = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-london-audition-confirmation";
    } else if ((optn_value=="Audition Only") && (optn_value=="Birmingham")) {
           window.location.href = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-birmingham-audition-confirmation";
    } else if ((optn_value=="Audition Only") && (optn_value=="Manchester")) {
           window.location.href = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-manchester-audition-confirmation"; 
    } else if ((optn_value=="Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value=="London")) {
           window.location.href = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-london-audition-confirmation";
    } else if ((optn_value=="Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value=="Birmingham")) {
           window.location.href = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-birmingham-audition-confirmation";
    } else if ((optn_value=="AAudition + Workshop") && (optn_value=="Manchester"))
           window.location.href ="http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-manchester-audition-confirmation"; 

}
    }

</script>

</form> 
<div id="formBottom">
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's nice to edit code out for readability, though I think you may have removed a tad too much. Can you edit your post to include your JavaScript? That's the more vital piece we need to see.

Comment: just added the full code, very new to amending code so not to sure what is best to show or not show. sorry for putting so much on there.

Comment: OK i think this is what i want to achieve with Javascripy

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Javascript

First of all, you'll have to get the selected option and then set the action based on the selected option.

you can get the value of selected option as follows,for eg

```
var optn = document.getElementById("signup_User8");
var optn_value= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Now, `optn_value` will contain the value of the option that is selected.

Then check the `optn_value` and set an action url accordingly.This action url can be set as the action of the form as below

```
form.action = new_action_url;
```

the whole code would be as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_action(form) {
        var optn = document.getElementById("signup_User8");
        var optn_value= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if(optn_value=="foo")
           form.action = new_action_url_1;
        else
           form.action = new_action_url_2;
    }
</script>
```

and in your HTML form add an `onsubmit` attribute which calls the Javascript function

```
<form onsubmit="get_action(this);">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go. Very new to this so it may take me some time

Comment: im not sure how far off this is but this is what I am trying to do. something like what i added to my question

Comment: and what is the rpoblem right now in this code? any errors?

Comment: yeah go on.. @StreamlineEmpire